# Reading dictionary from file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a huge base of lockers assigned to people in a file with this structure:

```
'paul':'locker.01'
'robert':'locker.02'
'julia':'locker.03'
'rosalind':'locker.04'
```

I need to create a script which will read this file as a dictionary like so:

```
{'paul':locker.01
'robert':locker.02
'julia':locker.03
'rosalind':locker.04}
```

So far I've created this script but I'm stuck. Anyone have done this before?

```
f = open('C:/file.txt', 'r')
for i in f.readlines():
    i = i[0:-1]    
    print(i)
```

Comment: Someone has certainly done it before. You might want to look at the  `csv` module or any tutorial on reading and parsing text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
result = {}
with open('thefile.txt') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        name, locker_number = line.replace("'", "").split(':')
        result[name] = locker_number
print(result)
```

Note that doing this is probably not a good approach. What if there are two Peter, three Julias?

So maybe this is better for you:

```
result = {}
with open('thefile.txt') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        name, locker_number = line.replace("'", "").split(':')
        if not name in result:
            result[name] = [locker_number]
        else:
            result[name].append(locker_number)

print(result)

for name in result:
    result[name] = ', '.join(result[name])  # will return a string of comma separated lockers.

print(result)
```

This would create a list of locker numbers assigned to that name.

Comment: Looks like the user is using python 3 from their print statement

Comment: Thanks, it's working however values are looking like this: ['locker.01']. Sorry for complaining, I'm new in Python, and this script is class assingment.

Comment: No problem. Well, what you want wouldn't be possible :/ locker.01 would raise an error as the python interpreter would think you are referencing to a class locker() and trying to access its value .01

Comment: i.e. you will need those values to be strings, there is no other way around it :/

Comment: Updated my answer to give you two different output options, one a list and one a string.

Comment: Actually it may work for what I'm developing, thanks again :)

Comment: Cool, glad I could help! Best of luck, happy coding!